# WordPress tinymce issue in article posting

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

Found 1 strange issue in WordPress article posting for one specific user.

1. User adds article in tinymce HTML mode
2. Again trying to add new post in tinymce Visual mode. not actually posted, just switched the tinymce slected tab from HTML to Visual
3. User tried to open post saved in HTML mode in setp 1, it shows tinymce Visual mode active in Tabs but icons loaded are from HTML mode. The tinymce content is not view-able now, content is there but not viewable, If i press CTRL+A, i can view the content and it also blocking other features as Editing draft, logout etc.
4. Now if user again trying to add new post, and selects HTML from tinymce tabs and exit from page
5. He tries to edit post added in setp 1, now it is showing correctly.

No issue in content as i tried to copy and paste this content in new post and it working fine.

It is not happening for all users. And 1 more point the icons loading in Visual mode are very less than found in Admin account.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Also I think this may have more to do with javascript than anything, are you able to post any debug issues that you can see in [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Chrome Inspect](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) to see if their are any errors thrown?

Comment: Javascript error in firebug : ReferenceError: switchEditors is not defined
It is not allowing to switch tinymce mode.

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle or live exaple for this? can you post your tinymce configuration?

Comment: have you upgraded/installed any plugin or the upgraded wordpress core ?
Its a javascript/jquery error , check the error with firebug if there is any

Comment: Turn off plugins one by one to find a culprit. How many are you running anyways?

Comment: Your question is not clear. But, for the CTRL+A, are you copy-pasting the content? If so, some times it may occur depending on from what kind of document you are copy-pasting the content.

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin - http://wordpress.ckeditor.com/. It replaces tinymce and many people find it more 'user friendly'. It has a 'Source' mode that seems to behave better than the HTML mode of tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your js-code using firebug.

Probably TinyMCE cannot initialize correctly, because of an JS error occuring earlier (in your js code or in wordpress plugin, i.e. Secure WordPress).

Check this, might help: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/uncaught-referenceerror-switcheditors-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can try is go to Users > Your Profile, disable visual editor while editing, save the settings and then uncheck that box and save settings again.

After that, check if tinyMCE functions properly, otherwise, try to disable your plugins one by one to find out which plugin is causing the jQuery conflict.